# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed, After refreshing the springs applicationcontext

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I'm using springs **cron** job feature in that method i'm modifying value of one of the properties file and to get that new modified value i'm refreshing the application context (Its working fine), after refreshing the `application context` i'm getting

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed"
```

so any solution for this.Thank You for the help.

Comment: While refreshing the mysql connection is getting closed. So you need to restart the connection as well. Please post how you refresh the application context

Comment: @ViswanathL i'm new to this please correct me that, once i refresh the application context then entire configuration will be reloaded (including db connection). is it correct?

Comment: Sometimes it won't, if you are running in web server. In my case tomcat sometime won't restart the db connection and end up in these errors . try to restart instead of refresh

Comment: "ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) appctx;
configurableApplicationContext.refresh(); " and Transaction is applied to this method ("@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)") also cron job ("@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")")